# Using PayPal Smart Buttons - Javascript SDK unsafe (?)

Tags: paypal

To me it looks that using PayPal Smart Buttons (Javascript SDK) can be unsafe.

In the SDK url you have to send your PayPal client-id (
).
This means that every visitor of your site can see your PayPal client-id, so they might abuse that (if they want).

Am I right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The client id is a public credential, for client-side operations. The `secret` is not.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that's make sense.